# How do I refresh a Smart Table after clearing smart filters without the use of Go button in SAPUI5 application?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a smart table with smart filters in my UI5 application. The smart filters apply the filters to the table perfectly fine as well as clearing the filters on the table just fine. However, the framework requires the user to click on the Go button to apply any filter changes and then only will the table get refreshed. Is there a way to create a custom clear button that will automatically refresh the table upon clicking the clear button? (see screenshots below)

[image: Smart Filter Bar]

```
<smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="XxxxX" enableBasicSearch="true"
                        basicSearchFieldName="XxxxX1, XxxxX2, XxxxX3"
                        useDateRangeType="true" showClearOnFB="true">
                        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="XxxxX1" label="XxxxX1" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" visible="true" index="2"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="XxxxX2" label=XxxxX2" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" visible="true" index="3"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="XxxxX3" label="XxxxX3" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" visible="true" index="6"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
</smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>


<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable" entitySet="XxxxX" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="ResponsiveTable"
                                useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport" useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true"
                                persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding tablehdr"
                                beforeRebindTable='onBeforeRebindTable' afterVariantInitialise="onVariantLoad">
                                <ui:Table enableBusyIndicator="true" threshold="200" class=" smartTableHeader" id="customTable" cellClick="onCellPress">
```

Comment: Set the property `liveMode` of the [`sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar) to `true`. > If set the search will be automatically triggered, when a filter value was set via the change event. No need to press the "Go" button.